# Need help printing linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list

When I call printList function in my main, it does not print all of the values even thought 
the values are there (I checked manually in the printList function)

```
void printList(listNode *start)
{
    listNode *currentPosition = start->next;


    threadList *t;
    t= currentPosition->tList->next;

    cList *c;
    c = currentPosition->tList->next->cpuList->next;

    if (currentPosition == NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (currentPosition != NULL)
        {
            printf("process #: %d # of thread: %d\n",currentPosition->processNumber,currentPosition->numThread);

            while (t != NULL)
            {

                printf("thread #: %d Arrival time: %d # CPU: %d\n",t->threadNumber,t->arrivalTime,t->numCPU);


                while (c != NULL)
                {

                    printf("Burst #: %d CPU Time: %d io Time: %d\n",c->cNum,c->cpuTime,c->ioTime);

                    c=c->next;
                }


                t=t->next;
            }
            currentPosition = currentPosition->next;
        }
    }
}
```

First node of all my linked list is a dummy node.
Can someone please help me figure out where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `printList`, it looks like you are setting `t` and `c` initially and then never updating them.

If you move

```
t= currentPosition->tList->next;
c = currentPosition->tList->next->cpuList->next;
```

to just inside of

```
while (currentPosition != NULL) {
```

Then I think it will work (I don't have a compiler handy).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!! i just needed to move t inside the 1st while loop and c inside the 2nd while loop